# Samsung Galaxy Spica won't boot up fully. Just restarts over and over

Tags: reboot, crashes, samsung-galaxy-spica

My Samsung galaxy won't turn on properly. Basically it turns on, shows the 'OMG screen' which it does when it crashes, then goes to the Samsung loading bar, but then goes back to the crash screen. It keeps going in a loop forever! 
I tried a hard reset, which if I understand correctly is holding down the volume down key and end call key, but this did nothing. 
(Sorry I'm not good at describing, hope this is clear!)
Thanks!

Comment: Did you made any changes to the phone recently? Flashing custom OS?

Comment: Can you provide a logcat and use http://pastebin.com to get at the contents of the logcat by selecting the text in the log, copying it into clipboard, paste into the said site for others to see?

Answer (score 1):

Try booting in safe mode. To do this simply press the power button while holding MENU + BACK